# Regarding the Uniformization theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

Trying to understand or get intuition for  [uniformization thm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) but there is a stumbling block..

The doughnut/torus genus $ g=1,$ Euler characteristic $\chi=0, $  has two demarcation rings  between areas of Gaussian curvature $ K>0,K<0 $ that is known.

However the two holed g=2 Pretzel $\chi<0 $ is supposed to have a constant negative sectional curvature, being one among hyperbolic 2-manifolds. By a rough hand sketch I have delineated /demarcated regions (on the visible side) where $ K>0 $ region can lie alongside the $ K<0 $ region:

[image]

It is consistent with Gauss-Bonnet theorem but how so? what am I missing here?.. a distinction between $(\chi, g) ?$ .. or sectional and Gaussian curvatures? or  between conformal/isometric mappings?

Thanks for helping to clarify..

Comment: I don't know much about the uniformisation theorem other than its statement, but just because a smooth $2$-manifold admits a metric of constant Gauss curvature doesn't mean there exists an isometric immersion of that manifold into $\mathbb{R}^3$. A simple example is the flat torus, which has an isometric embedding into $\mathbb{R}^4$ but not $\mathbb{R}^3$. Does that answer your question or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The key paragraph on the Wikipedia page is here: "Each such is conformally equivalent to a unique closed 2-manifold of constant curvature, so a quotient of one of the following by a free action of a discrete subgroup of an isometry group..."

Comment: @Vishnu M: There is real science in Liouville' equation $ \Delta_{LaplaceBeltrami}\; log f = -K $ ,  f is conformal factor. But only particular examples can make  things clearer. Btw, I would have liked naming it something like conformal equivalence thm.